# Polygon to Raster Cells Are Stretched Out

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro

I am using ArcGIS Pro, polygon to raster tool. I am converting a large set of polygons (over 100,000) into a raster, using a cell size of 0.0016 (the default is 0.0098). When the operation is complete, it creates cells that are very stretched out horizontally. The cells seem to be the correct vertical distance, but are way too wide. I tried the operation with the same inputs but on a small selection of polygons, and it worked fine.

[image]

Comment: What CRS / units are you dealing with? Also, whenever I use polygon to raster, there is no default cell size.

Comment: I'm using GCS_WGS_1984. I think the cell size is a function of the data set- the little information box next to cell size states, "The default cell size when a feature dataset is used as input to a tool is to take the width or height (whichever is shorter) of the extent of the feature dataset, divided by 250."